# Is this an example of a hostile moderation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

After a long time, I have added [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134693) on Stack Overflow thinking of receiving some help. I spent quite some time trying to make my question shorter and to the point. I added relevant link and posted a question. Within 10 minutes my question got closed and tagged as duplicate.

This is really heartbreaking. Why are moderators in such a hurry and how quickly they judge? Will it be too much to let a question afloat an hour or so? What harm is being caused by such question. Is that moderation?
I feel repelled by this experience and would likely refrain from posting on Stack Overflow. I hope the moderators develop a little more patience and be a bit kind.

---

Update: A few clarifications

I don't mind finding an answer fast (but sadly the question linked does not answer my question).

I can best describe the situation as a "decision to close made by {xyz} in rush". I am willing to rephrase/extend my original question; if there were a comment asking for more details or a indication that another question exists that answers my question I would happily add details or close/delete my own question for the latter case.

What I recall is that earlier there used to be a 5 close votes before a question was closed and usernames were visible making it possible to get a direct input from those users. This time I didn't know who closed it and why. The question that was linked is an extremely general question and my question goes a bit deeper than that.

Finally, I do realise that I myself had screwed by trying to keep my question short (intended to save time of other users) and it misled other people to close the question. I understand moderation might be a frustrating task but I don't think being jumpy to conclusions help (applicable to myself as well). I personally would rather add a comment or two before putting a close vote (and I did expect the same).

PS: Thankyou folks for re-opening my question!

Comment: Eh, i wouldn't consider it hostile. Closing duplicates quickly helps prevent people from wasting time answering something that is already answered and makes the question act as a better sign post to reach the answer. In the rare event a dupe closure is wrong, all you need to do is edit the question with clarification that clearly shows why it isn't a duplicate, and/or do what you've done (comment @ the closer and/or make a meta post, but try to avoid accusing people of things they haven't done.)

Comment: Consider rephrasing your post here. I do not know `c++` so I cannot judge, but if there was an Answer on the duplicate, that would be awesome, no? :)

Comment: If I see a question and know it's answered already and find the duplicate, how long should I wait before telling the question poster "Hey, here's your answer!"? I assume people asking questions want answers, so if I can give them their answer in 10 minutes or less, I surely will. The only reason I could suppose you are upset about the speed is if it didn't provide you an answer: are you asserting that the duplicate was incorrect? If so, that needs to be made clear here, otherwise it seems like you're complaining about getting an answer too fast.

Comment: Why is it "heartbreaking" to have someone carefully search and find a previously-asked question that provides the answer to yours? Why do you think the person needed more time than they took to make the decision?

Comment: Could you edit your question here to explain about whether you think the duplicate declaration is wrong? Presently we don't know if you think your question is obviously not a duplicate, and the question was closed wrongly, or you think that questions that are duplicate should not be closed if a lot of time was spent writing them.

Comment: Aside: the closer is not an elected moderator (sometimes known as a "diamond moderator", like Cody commenting above). The closer is a "gold badge holder", and they are judged to have such expertise in the subject tag that they are allowed to close posts on their own.

Comment: Duplicate questions literally answers your question. You ask wanting an answer, got a duplicate which contains the answer, you read it, you get answer. OR, If the duplicate doesn't help, just edit your question stating the dupe doesn't help because... How is this hostile at all?

Comment: I'll go on record saying that I hate it when that duplicate is used. It's an omnibus. Without a comment pointing the asker to which of the dozens of answers applies, it's pretty much useless. Unfortunately you don't provide enough information to pinpoint exactly which answer is correct, and at the end of the day, it's more useful than getting a Needs Debugging Details close.

Comment: That's precisely the cases where it should be used, @user4581301.

Comment: 10 minutes to closure? That's hardly quick moderation at all.

Comment: Agreed. There is no better alternative. We can't point to a narrower interpretation. That dupe is hard to use, but it's the best best answer the question can hope for in its current state.

Comment: If/when more information is provided that makes it *not* a duplicate, then it can be re-opened, just as it could be re-opened if it were (less helpfully) closed as "lacks debugging details".

Comment: "Is this an example of **hostile**" - instant no, does not matter what follows.

Comment: Linker errors get short shrift at SO, such a question rarely contains sufficient info to diagnose the cause.  Or commonly, as here, the OP doesn't even realize it is a linker error.  As such the linked duplicate is absolutely essential background to make headway.  I posted a guess at the reason in a comment, we can't use guesses as answers.

Comment: @CodyGray "Why is it "heartbreaking" to have someone carefully search and find a previously-asked question that provides the answer to yours?" Considering it's well known that many regular users are having issues interacting with SO and are becoming bitter and hostile, is your question a genuine attempt to gain better understanding of how other people experience SO, or is it a rhetorical question aimed at invalidating OP's experience? Of course both of us understand how this could be experienced negatively even though we also know the rules of the game.

Comment: Yes, it's a genuine question, @Alex. I take accusations of hostility very seriously, as a person and as a moderator. That means I investigate them thoroughly and may even take action against the offenders. It *also* means that I am quite sensitive to *spurious* accusations of the same. I investigate them equally as thoroughly, but I end up annoyed because what I see is someone genuinely trying to be helpful and getting accused of being...something else. The gap between the two is mind-boggling to me. Nobody left a rude or embittered comment on the question on the main site; I checked.

Comment: @CodyGray Why would to take accusations of hostility seriously? We have a system where we want to engage as many users as possible in this community while at the same time enforcing much higher standards compared to what people otherwise are used to. Of course people will misunderstand, feeling hurt and using stronger language than might be motivated. But we are the supposed to be the parents here, right?

Comment: @Alex There are a couple of reasons why I take these accusations seriously. One reason is because I'm an elected moderator, meaning it's one of my jobs! Another reason is because there is sometimes truth to them. In other words, sometimes rude comments *do* get left on Stack Overflow, mostly from experienced users who get frustrated. It is understandable, but it doesn't make it OK. We do want everyone to have a positive experience here, as you said, while also upholding our quality standards *and* our Code of Conduct. We can have quality without being jerks. That's what mods help to enforce.

Comment: @CodyGray Do you think OP perceived that question as a genuine request to understand their frustration? I'm not even emotionally invested in OPs efforts to engage in this platform and I still perceived that as a rhetorical question meant to simply invalidate the "heartbreak" that OP feels. Considering the obvious state of emotions that the OP expresses, I wouldn't be surprised if OP perceived that comment as you being a jerk.

Comment: It's a serious problem when genuine questions get interpreted as "being a jerk". I don't know what I can do about that. Unfortunately, it does not seem to be a problem that I can resolve.

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry but you are obviously intelligent and articulate enough that I don't believe for a second that you don't understand how the nuances of language and context together is as important if not even more important as the literary meaning of words, nor that you can't see how that question could be received completely differently depending on if you are on the side of the frustrated but well-intentioned OP or the frustrated but well-intentioned janitors here at SO.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was hostile moderation. The speed of the actions itself is not really a sign of hostility, if one thinks about it. After and with the help of some edits, the question has been reopened and is ontopic now. I hope it gets an answer. The initial reaction may have been received as harsh, but I wonder what the alternative would have been? As an answerer, I know that I don't have enough time to help everyone and closing is a signal that others don't need to bother, which means there is more time for even completely others. It's how the curation of content here works.

Comment: There simply aren't more free resources available to do more tutoring on how to make questions ontopic (and that's why this idea will never fly unless there is a surge in programming experts with too much time coming). There may be mistakes though and the meta community should be aware of and try to measure and minimize curation errors. Communicating even better what curation actions mean, what users can do in reply and how the sites works is also very important, but there are already so many initiatives about it... one more would probably not really help.

Answer (score 54):

## Don't take moderation decisions *personally*.

This has nothing to do with *you*.  This is someone who is an expert in C++ who believes that your question is related to or similar to another question.

If you don't believe it is, **address it in your question** by providing additional context as to why it isn't a duplicate.  **Do not simply say that your question is not a duplicate and offer *no* explanation as to why** as you'll have an even worse time than you have now.

Comment: Side remark: without taking moderation decisions personally, we can still unsatisified with them, particularly if we are the objects of the negative decision.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica: And yet, the OP seemed to have the hallmark reaction of, "this is an affront to me and is impacting my choice to ask questions here."

Comment: Yes, but the OP has right. The stats of the SO are not very nice, and meta sites imho mostly agree that it is caused by the attitude what the newbies experience. This attitude, what I experienced as a newbie, caused the attitude of my meta posts in the following years. If he does not take it personally, then maybe he does not visit the meta, but still silently leaves (or won't become a very enthusiast user).

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica:  They'd have a right to take it personally if the fact that their content was being moderated in the way it was moderated was *explicitly* because of who the OP is.  Because it isn't, that right does not apply here ***in the slightest***.  Being upset about moderation action doesn't mean that it's OK to feel like moderators have it out for you, and while I know that decades of bulletin boards and secular community moderation have led others to think *otherwise*, that's not the case on Stack Overflow, full stop.

Comment: @Makoto We are still dealing with people and it's obvious that SO have problems here considering the amount of people who basically hate SO even though it is the fantastic resource it is. Which in turn leads to people on this side are getting tired of being accused of disrespectful behavior and likewise are getting entrenched and easily irritated, which you yourself and many others display here when you react to a disheartened user by questioning their "right" to feel like they do, instead of respecting their frustration but at the same time being firm and educating.

Comment: You can't have these much higher standards on quality of content that SO has compared to other resources without also having to have a really good system to communicate and educate regular users. At least if you want to avoid alienating a huge amount of good-intentioned people that simply just don't quite get the hang of it yet. And this has broken down a long time ago, and the community here has gotten hostile towards everything that, however incorrectly, could be interpreted as sacrificing standards to "being kind".

Comment: @Alex:  If they're frustrated or hate the site, then it's really the fault of the site for throwing a user into the deep end, not the users who are attempting to stem the tide of poor quality questions.  I'm gonna say out loud that I really don't care *how* they feel about the site; we're not asking a user for their emotional evaluation.  We only care about if their question is clear, on-topic and if it's code oriented, that it's reproducible and has a snippet of code that we can follow.

Comment: @Alex:  **We curators do not own, in any way, a system to communicate en masse to every user of the site.**  All we're able to do is communicate in small fits and bursts and pockets.  So, if the company wants to do something to fix its reputation, it can start by **conveying the message that we curators have been conveying this entire damn time** as opposed to framing us as the bad guys.

Comment: @Alex:  We are being quite kind in that we are not looking at an individual when they ask a question.  We're looking at a *question*.  I can't fix any stigma if the user thinks that they're being personally affronted if their question is poor, because that's not what I'm saying, that's never what I've said and that's not where we're going with this.  No one, on the other hand, is showing any kind of kindness to the misguided fools that are we who try to keep question quality on this site on the up and up.

Comment: So I stress once more @Alex: If we were talking about the **individual**, they would have a right and *be* in the right to take an action of moderation personally.  Since we're not, that right **does not exist**.

Answer (score -15):

The site has to deal with an unthinkable amount of crap, while there is only a few people helping to clean it up. This has leaded to various problems, namely:

- Some people got maybe too much power. In your case, people with 1000 upvotes to their answers in a tag, can single sidedly close (or reopen) questions as dupe.
- To clean up somehow might be still better than doing nothing. But having less effort to moderate also means that there are more false decisions in both directions.

Beside that, well... my opinion is very far from that the avid moderators (reviewers) would be all nice guys. But if moderation would not mean that you need to click 9 times for closure on the spot, and 1 times can you think if the post *might* remain open, their - sometime really hostile - decisions would be easily and quickly reverted.

Your question is a border case of being a duplicate. The close voters opinion was that it is a dupe (= answers in the original post should answer also your question). My opinion, among 2 other people, was that it is enough different to live without the dupe closure, so I clicked a reopen, but without saying that the original closer had made a mistake. It was a border case.

You want nicer moderation, okay! I totally agree. But... you have 500 rep, meaning that you already can take part some review queues. Your activity history say that you made only about 20 reviews in the last year, since you can do it.

You want a change, then *be the change*. The queues are waiting you.

Comment: 'The queues are waiting you' well, with an SO up/downvoting ratio of 358/1, the OP is clearly not capable of effective curation:(

Comment: @MartinJames Curation does not mean to everything close-down-del. Others do the reverse. The balance is important + he might make also comments and edits.

Comment: @MartinJames + if he see the crap, he will think differently.

Comment: "*... dupe (= answers in the original post should answer also your question)*". No, a dupe simply means that the question itself has been asked before. There may not be a high quality answer on the original post; that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @cigien This is a too broad definition. These are clearly not dupes, the orig question is not the same as the dupe. And it is also not helpful - OP should find his answer on the answers of the orig.

Comment: I'm not referring to the OP's post or its closure. I mean in general, the only requirement for a duplicate is that the questions be the same. If there are no good answers on the target, then there are other mechanisms such as bounties, etc. that can be placed on the target, in order to receive attention, and hopefully better answers.

Comment: @cigien "the only requirement for a duplicate is that the questions be the same" I've bumped into this before when I questioned why some posts were closed as duplicates, then I was told that it is the *answers* that matter most. If question A and B have the same answer C, then A and B are duplicates. I've never understood that logic.

Comment: @Alex That's why the explanation for duplicates was updated to say: *"This question already has answers here:....link....A community member has associated this post with a similar question."*

Comment: @cigien Huhh, that is really sad. [Because 610681 questions are closed as dupe, while they are the same only in 213 cases.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1340967/count-of-dupe-vs-count-of-exact-dupes) Something might be wrong. Maybe the dupe closure customs, or your definition. Or both. :-)

Comment: @MartinJames I also don't have any problem with his upvote ratio, because someone has to balance [them](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1329227/downvoter-trolls-low-rep-many-downs).

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica why is balance needed?  There are far more bad questions that deserve downvotes than good questions that deserve upvotes.  That ratio is massivey-inappropriate.

Comment: @MartinJames Oh yeah. Particularly "Vote Dukakis" is surely a good-standing newbie, with his 154 rep. Unfortunately, he finds exclusively bad questions. He found 16000, until now, and only 150 good ones. What a bad luck. Sad...